# Compile wxWidgets applications in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, widget, wxwidgets

I'm using Windows 11 OS, wx widgets 3.2.2.1 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.

I installed wxWidgets.

I then created a C++ empty project and properly configured it for wxWidgets.

I created a source file (project2.cpp) and added some simple code to it.

I compiled the application.

The build was successful, but there was no exe files for my project in both x64\release and project2\x64\release folders. I even checked the debug folders, but there was no exe files for the application.

I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it multiple times, but still no exe files. Creating another project and configuring it for wxWidgets did not solve the problem for me.

Here's my application code (project2.cpp):

```cpp
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);
};

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame("My App");
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(300, 200))
{
    // Here I can add controls to the application
}

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Comment: In the absence of any compile or link errors, these kind of issues are typically related to antivirus software.

Comment: @bozorgmehr, how did install wxWidgets? Did you get a pre-built version or you get the source code?

Comment: @bozorgmehr, BTW, there a minimal sample provided for you to test the library. It is located inside `<wxWidgets_base_dir\samples\minimal`. It is build-able and runnable out of the box, even if you didn't build the library.

Comment: I disabled Antivirus before compiling the application, I downloaded wx source code and copyed it on C: how to use that samples, BTW for me its better to solve this problem since some times I need to make new applications, without any samples

Answer (score 0):

@bozorgmehr,

In order to use the sample all you need to do is:

1. Open MSVC
2. Go to File -> Open Solution and navigate to c:\wxWidgets\samples\minimal (please adjust the directory name here)
3. Open the file minimal_vc17.sln
4. Go to Build -> Build.

5 Execute the binary

Let us know if there any issues.

Now in order to make a new project you have many choices:

1. You can use the minimal sample solution as a template for a new project. You can copy it to some dedicated location or use it in place.
2. You can use a provided MSVC template solution file.
3. You can create an empty GUI project and copy whatever in the minimal sample sln file manually. That way you will learn what is wxWidgets internals for building the application.

HTH.

EDIT:

In order to build everything what you should do is:

In the MSVC:

Go to File -> Open Solution

Navigate to `c:\wxWidgets\build\msw` and open wx_vc17.sln

Go to Build->Batch Build

In the dialog shown, put a checkmark next to everything that has Debug.

Click Build.

This will take sometime. After that you will have everything built and now ready to do the development with wxWidgets.

Comment: okay samples worked properly without errors for me, thank you for your help: my problem is just how to use this in new projects: currently I'm newbie to wx widgets and just working with this sln file, but later I will need to make new projects, then how to use this sample folder with new projects? I dont want to have extra files, one time I created a new project and copied the minimal_vc17.sln in to the new project folder, but I got errors related to bass and coar not found.

Comment: @bozorgmehr, I t5hink I answered that question as well. Also please see a correction to my answer.

Comment: Allso - are you project is wxWidgets based, or wxWIdgets is a dependency of some portion of it.

Comment: I get an error when I even use this sample .sln files: C1083. Cannot open include file: 'wx/setup.h': No such file or directory: I think i need to copy it again, so I copied setup.h from include\\msvc\\wx to include\\wx but then I got more errors: This error occurred when I configured my project as a release, I compiled it once without any errors, and then I used the exe file of the application, and then I got errors when compiling the app
I reinstalled wx widgets 100 times, but still this error

Comment: @bozorgmehr, sorry, you need to be more specific. In the first reply you said the sample worked for you and now you say it does not. Also - which path did you took when creating you project (as I presume the second time you are talking about your own code vs the sample).